# Email not sending when task is assigned, but email sends when task changes (SP2010)

Tags: sharepoint

I had been using SP2010 Beta for 7 months or so, and had the task lists set up such that when a task was assigned to someone, an email was sent to that person. I moved over to RTM, and am having trouble getting this to work. An email will be sent to the person assigned to the task when something in the task changes, but not when it is first created/assigned. Can someone help shed some light to this? I have smtp configured correctly, and the task list's advanced settings are set so that Email Notification is sent when ownership is assigned or when an item changes.

Please Advise.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Is the task created/assigned by another user (i.e. a person) or is it created programmatically via a web part or some other code?

Comment: created/assigned by another user

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have SharePoint already configured for outgoing emails.
2. Make sure that you have alerts for the document library turned on if you are testing with the document library.
3. Run this command from `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\BIN: stsadm -o updatealerttemplates -filename "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\XML\customalerttemplates.xml" -url`
4. Run this command: `stsadm -o setproperty -pn job-immediate-alerts -pv "every 1 minutes"`
5. Run this command from the command prompt: `iisreset`
6. Run this command from the command prompt: `services.msc`
7. From the services window, restart the Windows SharePoint Services Timer.